# Magento mutisite theme issue

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento multisite functionality using this tutorial on my localhost:
http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html
Using it I have successfully created multisite in magento but I am unable to set theme in my another site which I created. I have tried to system->design and system->configuration->design both options but did not get any success yet.
The another site is rendering by base/default but I had set it to default/modern.
Please tell me what is going wrong?
PS: sorry I cant post snap but I have following configurations:
Main Website
   Main Website Store
      Default Store View
    mytheme/default     
My Site
   My Store
      My Store View
    default/modern

Comment: can you please add design config screenshot here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I got the issue, 
I have to set base url as `localhost/magento/` and base link as `localhost/magento/mysite2/` but I had set `localhost/magento/mysite2/` for both. anyway thanks for help.